# Heroku External Objects: can it be used in standard reports in Salesforce?

Tags: reporting

Is it possible, from a Salesforce Org, to create a Report/Dashboard on a Heroku External object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to create a report on Herku external object in salesforce.

To create the report , you need to :

1. Setup Home > External Objects > Edit
2. Select “Enable Reports” on the external object.

Enabling reports creates the following in the Other Reports report type category.

•A report type for the external object

•A report type for each lookup relationship in which both objects allow reports

***There are various reporting considerations when dealing with External objects in Salesforce*** :

• When you run a report, your org performs a request callout for each external object in the report.

• When you run a report that’s in the joined format, your org performs separate request callouts for each block.

• If the URL length of a report callout approaches or exceeds 2 KB, your org splits the request into multiple HTTP calls, with each URL being less than 2 KB. However, with the cross-org adapter for Salesforce Connect, report callouts that exceed 2 KB fail and are not split into multiple calls.

• A report that includes an external object fetches up to 20,000 records for the primary object. If the report is customized to include child objects, the total number of rows can be greater or less than 10,000, depending on how many child records are fetched. To obtain more relevant external object rows, try customizing the report.

For more info click on this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.platform_connect_considerations_reports.htm&type=5)